# Need to display data as it's calculated in a scrolling window using Swift on Mac

Tags: swift, macos, dynamic, textview

I have an app on the mac which I want to display in a window as the data is calculated. I'm looking to do the same type of display as what xcode shows when a running app prints data or the terminal app when doing a directory. Nothing complicated although I would want to scroll back to see earlier data.

I can do it using TableView I suppose, but that seems to make it more difficult than I want.

This seems to be a simple thing to do but I look at things like NSScrollView and it only displays after the calculation is done. Some sample code would be wonderful.

**Update1:**
Trying NSScrollView (below), I'm able to output a string to it in ViewDidLoad, but in my dataGenerator func in the ViewController, it is nil. Used storyboard to create the ViewController with the NSScrollView in it.

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    ViewController().dataGenerator()
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}
```

}

class ViewController: NSViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var TextDataOutlet: NSScrollView!

func dataGenerator() {
    TextDataOutlet.documentView!.insertText("Test String2")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    TextDataOutlet.documentView!.insertText("Test String1")
}
```

}

Test String1 appears in the ViewController but crashes with a nil when trying to display Test String2.

I've tried various suggestions in searches, but I guess I'm not searching for the right thing.

**Update2:**
When I call the viewController from the AppDelegate, the ViewController window doesn't show up until the dataGenerator routine has completed. How do make the display visible while the dataGenerator routine is running?

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    let storyboardName = NSStoryboard.Name(stringLiteral: "Main")
    let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil)
            
    let storyboardID = NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(stringLiteral: "textDataStoryWCboardID")

    if let textDisplayWC = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: storyboardID) as? NSWindowController
    {
        let passDisplayVC = textDisplayWC.contentViewController as? ViewController
        passDisplayVC!.dataGenerator()

        NSApp.runModal(for: NSPanel(contentViewController: passDisplayVC! ))
    }
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}
```

}
class ViewController: NSViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var TextDataOutlet: NSScrollView!

func dataGenerator() {
    let now = Date()
    let step = TimeInterval( 2 )
    let end = now + 30
    
    var current = now
    var printString:String = ""
    var displayString:String = ""

    while( current <= end )
    {
        if( Date() >= current )
        {
            printString = String(format: "Time: %@", current as CVarArg )
            displayString = printString + "\n"

            print( printString )
            
            TextDataOutlet.documentView!.insertText(displayString)

            current += step
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    TextDataOutlet.documentView!.insertText("viewDidLoad Test String1\n")
}
```

}

**Update 3:**
I fixed the problem by creating a separate thread for the dataGenerator. I tried posting the code, but stackoverflow is preventing me from posting it because it didn't like me including global variables so oh well.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nstextview+log

Comment: "what I'm doing wrong"  You are not showing a single line of code.  So nobody can tell.

Comment: `ViewController()` creates a new `ViewController` so `TextDataOutlet` is `nil`.

Comment: Fixed it so that TextDataOutlet isn't nil, but it doesn't display the window or contents until the dataGenerator is done.

Comment: Is the dataGenerator blocking the main thread?

Comment: Probably. It's called from the AppDelegate (passDisplayVC!.dataGenerator() in Update2 above).